# Getting partial results after using concat on observables

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have the following streams:

```
Observable<SomeResponseObject> method(){
    List<MyPojo> stream1...
    Observable<List<MyPojo>> stream2...

    return Observable.concat(Observable.from(stream1).toList(),stream2).map(users->
        createSomeResponseObject(users);
}
```

However when i debug SomeResponseObject I only see the results of **stream1** (missing results of stream2)

executing it via unit-testings:

```
        myClass.method().toBlocking().first();
```

stream2 created this way:

```
 return Observable.from(Arrays.asList(new MyPojo("user7"))).toList();
```

What am I missing with concatenation of those two lists?

Comment: Are you sure the first observable completes? `concat` will emit the elements from the first observable until it completes, then it will start with the elements of the second observable. http://rxmarbles.com/#concat

Comment: @LordRaydenMK the first one I am turning into observable on the fly.  when I check 'users' on debugger I see only the ones from Stream1 - thats the first one right?

Comment: Yes. Stream 2 should start after stream 1 completes. You should use `merge` if you want to combine values from both as they arrive.

Comment: I tried with merge(replaced with concat. still getting only the first stream's objects within my results

Comment: How are you creating stream2 ?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK updated my question with details how I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two elements after the concatenation but you only await the first one:

```
myClass.method().toBlocking().first();
```

I'm guessing you want to wait for both:

```
myClass.method().toBlocking().last();
```

or get both at once packed together:

```
myClass.method().toList().toBlocking().first(); // returns List<List<MyPojo>>
```

Comment: isnt there a way to 'wait' for both responses inside myClass.method() before returning?